How do update the extracted files from an AppImage?
I have a nonlinear video editing program that I want to update. The problem is that I extracted the  AppImage files and now I cannot update it manually. How do I update the  AppImage that I had extracted?

Appimages are "portable" software. They aren't designed to be updated. The update, when (and if) published is another, different, appimage.
